# fingerprint recognition and windows hello stopped working on windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-11, fingerprint, windows-hello

After updating to WIN 11 my fingerprint recognition stopped working.
I've tried:
-updating the driver.
-re-installing the driver.
-edit registry values.
-disabling and re-enabling the driver.
-changed Credential Manage to automatic.
Nothing worked it still says that the option is currently unavailable.
I know a lot of people have the same problem as me but i couldn't find any solution for this problem.
Does anyone know how i can fix it?
I'm using Lenovo Ideapad C340-15IML, my win version is 22H2 (22623.891)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried: -updating the driver. -re-installing the driver. -edit
> registry values.

Fingerprint works here:  Two Lenovo ThinkPads with Fingerprint Reader. Windows 11 Pro V22H2 or above (Insider).

It is not clear what damage the registry changes did.

**(1) Try (the "try" will likely be in vain) DISM / SFC**

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(2) Try a Windows 11 Repair Install**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(3) If nothing works, do a fresh install of Windows 11**

If nothing works, there could be User Profile damage or Operating System Damage.  The easiest fix for this is to back everything up and reinstall Windows 11 fresh.

**Finally** you may have a hardware or connection issue with the Fingerprint Reader and so you may wish to contact Lenovo Support.

Comment: i tried doing it and it still says that its unavailable

Comment: You may have a hardware or connection issue with your Fingerprint reader. Also ask Lenovo Support.